# recording audio from a mic and plotting it

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to learn a basic function of matlab and that is to record audio from mic and then plot it for a noise cancellation project. This is what I currently have:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
fs=24;
n=20000;
handles.signal1 = audiorecorder(n,fs,'Double');
msgbox('Recorded','Status');
guidata(hObject,eventdata, handles);

function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
fs1=24;
n=20000;
handles.noise1= audiorecorder(n,fs1,'Double');
msgbox('Recorded','Status');
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

I get this error at line 6:

> not enough input arguments

Comment: In which location above error is coming ?

Comment: @KarthickRajan line 6

Comment: Line 6 has `guidata(hObject,eventdata, handles);` but further on you have `guidata(hObject, handles);`.
Where is the code for the `guidata()` function and how many arguments does it take?

Answer (score 0):

In line 6 remove **eventdata** and try it will work because guidata accept only 1 or 2 arguments

syntax for  **guidata**

1. `guidata(object_handle,data)`
2. `data = guidata(object_handle)`